# Apache with PHP support under Yocto Project

Tags: php, apache, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am trying to install apache2 with PHP support on Linux created with the Yocto Project. Unfortunately there is only the PHP recipe and no extra package for the webserver. I figured out there are different ways to include PHP. The "module-way" should be the easiest one I guess.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239340/apache2-with-php-support-in-yocto) question (I have not enough reputations to comment) I have to change the `php.inc`.

Bitbake worked fine and I build my image successfully. But how can I "activate" these module? What files should I edit in which way since there is no PHP support out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php.inc` has apache2 as configuration; to enable, simply add this to your `local.conf`

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-php = " apache2 "
```

> ```
> PACKAGECONFIG ??= "mysql sqlite3 imap \
>                    ${@bb.utils.filter('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'ipv6 pam', d)} \
> "
> PACKAGECONFIG_class-native = ""
>
> PACKAGECONFIG[mysql] = "--with-mysql=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${prefix} \
>                         --with-mysqli=${STAGING_BINDIR_CROSS}/mysql_config \
>                         --with-pdo-mysql=${STAGING_BINDIR_CROSS}/mysql_config \
>                         ,--without-mysql --without-mysqli --without-pdo-mysql \
>                         ,mysql5"
>
> PACKAGECONFIG[sqlite3] = "--with-sqlite3=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
>                           --with-pdo-sqlite=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
>                           , \
>                           ,sqlite3"
> PACKAGECONFIG[pgsql] = "--with-pgsql=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${exec_prefix},--without-pgsql,postgresql"
> PACKAGECONFIG[soap] = "--enable-libxml --enable-soap, --disable-soap, libxml2"
> PACKAGECONFIG[apache2] = "--with-apxs2=${STAGING_BINDIR_CROSS}/apxs,,apache2-native apache2"
> PACKAGECONFIG[pam] = ",,libpam"
> PACKAGECONFIG[imap] = "--with-imap=${STAGING_DIR_HOST} \
>                        --with-imap-ssl=${STAGING_DIR_HOST} \
>                        ,--without-imap --without-imap-ssl \
>                        ,uw-imap"
> PACKAGECONFIG[ipv6] = "--enable-ipv6,--disable-ipv6,"
> ```

Comment: It works, thanks! I extended your answer since you need some changes in a conf file.