# Add modules to php/apache2 in Yocto

Tags: php, apache2, yocto

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239340/apache2-with-php-support-in-yocto) to a similar problem but it doesn't work for me.
In my `custom-meta-layer/recipes-core/images/<image>.bbappend` I wrote:

```
EXTRA_OEMAKE += "build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1=. --enable-mbstring"

IMAGE_INSTALL += " \
    rsync \
    php \
    php-cli \
    php-modphp \
    phpmyadmin \
    sqlite3 \   
    apache2 \
    nano \
    "
```

as suggested in the answer linked above.
But when I `bitbake <image>` I get:

> Nothing RPROVIDES 'php-modphp'

Did I not understand the answer? Or perhaps something has changed over the time?
I need to enable: `php-mbstring php-intl php-xml libapache2-mod-php` in order to let apache2 to show php pages.

Comment: Are you using a layer that has a recipe that rprovides php-modphp -- probably meta-oe?

Comment: You have to add `PACKAGECONFIG_pn-php = "mysql sqlite3 imap opcache openssl ${@bb.utils.filter('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'ipv6 pam', d)} apache2"` to local.conf or create equivalent `php_%.bbappend`.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen: actually, I'm confused because I cannot find a recipe for `php-modphp` even on http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/thud/recipes/?q=php-modphp

Comment: @Nayfe you should write answers, not comments :-) Thanks to your hint I was able to enable the module BUT 1. I had to re-create the same path (`meta-custom-layer/recipes-devtools/php/php_%.bbappend`. 2. it didn't copy `php-modphp` to the rootfs. I manually deployed it.

Comment: I write answers only when I'm sure, and in Yocto world, I'm not sure about anything ;)